# Additive latency for DRAM READ and WRITE commands

Tags: fpga, ddr, ddr3, dram, ddr2

In [TN-47-10 – DDR2 Posted CAS# Additive Latency Technical Note](https://application-notes.digchip.com/024/24-19971.pdf) , what does it exactly mean by **Additive latency (AL = 1) is only used for READ commands and will not affect WRITE command timing** ?

[image: DRAM_write_latency]

[image: DRAM_read_latency]

Comment: Please stop creating questions that are a few words followed by a dump of some document's text. You've done just that on a succession of your questions, despite being asked not to. This expects every reader to first re-interpret the text and see what your question actually is. It's also using the site as a personal helpline. Instead, write a thorough question that explains what you understand so far and the problem you have encountered, in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> *what does it exactly mean by Additive latency (AL = 1) is only used
> for READ commands and will not affect WRITE command timing ?*

When a host writes to any device (DDR included), clock and data travel to the device (from the host) and arrive together and synchronized but, they are slightly delayed. The device handles that just fine.

When a host reads a device, the device receives the information (clock etc.) some time after the host has transmitted it (call it latency time, \$t_L\$). The device then outputs the data and, some time later that data arrives at the host but, relative to the original clock signal produced by the host, the data arrives back at the host delayed by \$2\cdot t_L\$.

Hence, the host has to be aware of this latency and try to compensate for it so that it correctly reads the returning device data.